# Rails 3.1 using redis getting error: undefined method new for RedisStore:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I am trying to use redis and redis-store with rails 3.1; however I seem to get an error:

undefined method new for RedisStore:Module

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: You seem to call `new` on `RedisStore` which doesn't work because `RedisStore` is a module. Please post the code that throws the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed: https://github.com/jodosha/redis-store